# Finding batch file using parameter in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file (test.bat) which has the command `copy NUL test.txt`. I have a java program, when i run it and when i enter a URL in the web browser e.g `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam`, i get a result as either `{"result":true}` or `{"result":false}`. True means the java application has executed the batch file correctly (test.txt is created under the directory).

What i want to do now is, i want the java program to be able to take in parameters. E.g. User should be able to enter `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/testabc.bat` as the URL in web browser and the result should be `{"result":true}` if testabc.bat file is found and is executed (under desktop) and `{"result":false}` if the testabc.bat file is not found and not executed . (Note: All batch files are created under desktop filepath: `C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop`)

I have edited my controller to take in a parameter and done the @PathVariable. In my codes, the `fileName` variable refers to the batch file name that i have created (test.bat, test123.bat) Command in test.bat: `copy NUL test.txt` Command in test123.bat: `copy NUL test123.txt`. However, i keep getting the result as {"result": false}. Which means the java program is not able to find the batch file and execute it.

Here are my codes:

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

    String var = fileName;
    String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop" + var;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        return new ResultFormat(exitVal == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResultFormat(false);
    }
}
```

**ResultFormat.java**

```
private boolean result;

public ResultFormat(boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

**BatchFileController**

```
private static final String template = "Sum, %s!";  

@RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param}")
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName ) {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch(fileName);
}
```

**Application.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

What do i have to edit or what should i add to the codes to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop" + var;
```

Try to print the contents of `filePath`, i suspect that you come up  with something like this:

> C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktoptestabc.bat

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Could you please explain more? I'm quite new to this therefore i'm feeling abit confused